# XMPPFramework - How can I get a list of online and offline friends?

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

How can I get a list of online and offline friends using XMPPFramework in iOS?

I want to send buddy request to user. So how can I achieve this? Can somebody share some sample codes for me?

Thank you.

Comment: Ur requirement is something like, u want to show all offline and online users separately and if anyone goes online/offline ,that need to be reflected.r8?

Comment: if u want the answer , let me know the details.

Comment: yes I want that kind of stuff...

Comment: Sample code to retrieve the list could be found in the sample iPhone application in XMPPFramework: [XMPPFramework / Xcode / iPhoneXMPP / Classes / RootViewController.m](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/blob/master/Xcode/iPhoneXMPP/Classes/RootViewController.m)

Comment: @KeithOYS can you update the link?

Comment: @Vats Here you go: [Robbiehanson / XMPPFramework / Xcode / Examples / iPhoneXMPP / Classes / RootViewController.m](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/blob/master/Xcode/Examples/iPhoneXMPP/Classes/RootViewController.m)

Comment: @KeithOYS Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

By using these  methods you will get notified whole a user going to online/ offline, added, removed , updated etc.by using these methods you can update your contact list

```
- (void)xmppRoster:(XMPPRosterMemoryStorage *)sender didAddUser:(XMPPUserMemoryStorageObject *)user

- (void)xmppRoster:(XMPPRosterMemoryStorage *)sender didUpdateUser:(XMPPUserMemoryStorageObject *)user

- (void)xmppRoster:(XMPPRosterMemoryStorage *)sender didRemoveUser:(XMPPUserMemoryStorageObject *)user

- (void)xmppRoster:(XMPPRosterMemoryStorage *)sender
    didAddResource:(XMPPResourceMemoryStorageObject *)resource
          withUser:(XMPPUserMemoryStorageObject *)user

- (void)xmppRoster:(XMPPRosterMemoryStorage *)sender
 didUpdateResource:(XMPPResourceMemoryStorageObject *)resource
          withUser:(XMPPUserMemoryStorageObject *)user

- (void)xmppRoster:(XMPPRosterMemoryStorage *)sender
 didRemoveResource:(XMPPResourceMemoryStorageObject *)resource
          withUser:(XMPPUserMemoryStorageObject *)user
```

// To add buddy

```
- (void)addContactWithUserName:(NSString *)userName andNickName:(NSString *)nickName;
{
    if(userName)
    {
        XMPPJID *jid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@",userName,self.hostName]];
        if(nickName)
        {
            [_xmppRoster addUser:jid withNickname:nickName];
        }
        else
        {
            [_xmppRoster addUser:jid withNickname:nil];
        }
    }
else
{
    NSLog(@"missing userName");
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replay...
But, from which method you have listed out,I have to called addcontactwithusername method

Comment: Can u explain in detail

Comment: I had searched on google that we have to call didReceivePresence method to get presence of our friend. is it true?

Comment: Lot of ways we can implement XMPP.i think that also true

Comment: That means I have to call addContactWithUserName method from didReceivePresence. IS it?

Comment: do you have done any kind of file transfer using XMPPFramework? which is better from XEP-0065, XEP-0096. Any sample code for file transfer. If my Jabber server is 54.186.107.171.

Comment: No,am also searching for that

Comment: Hi suhail. I want my all friend list when my application starts how can i do that?