# XMPPFramework - How to identify in 'didReceiveIQ' whether response is user's contactList?

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I am sending request to my jabber server to get my contact list.

Now my problem is that `didReceiveIQ` method is called numberous times.

So how could I identify that when didReciveIQ is called, it should be my contact list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fetching contact list from jabber server

```
-(void)fetchRosterListWithUserId:(NSString *)userId // yourID
    {
        NSXMLElement *query = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"query" xmlns:@"jabber:iq:roster"];
        XMPPIQ *iq = [XMPPIQ iq];
        [iq addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:FETCH_ROSTER_DISCO_ID];
        [iq addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:userId];
        [iq addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"get"];
        [iq addChild:query];
        [_xmppStream sendElement:iq];
```

You can get the response back in

```
 - (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq
    {
       // You can identify the response by using @"id"
        if([[iq attributeStringValueForName:@"id"] isEqualToString:FETCH_ROSTER_DISCO_ID])
        {
                //Extract contact list from response here
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you. Is it compulsory to send presence? If Yes, then how to do that and how to manage my offline and online roster. can u please help me.

Comment: I dono that much about presence. i handling online/ offline by using the methods what i put answer for ur previous question

Comment: Listen, Right now I have created two array (1)array for online contact. (2) array for offline contacts. Now I am adding all contact in offline array. now what event to move online buddies into online array from offline array.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522526/how-can-i-get-list-of-online-and-offline-friend-list-using-xmppframework/24530294#24530294 .check this methods..This methods will getting called if some go online/offline.U can compare with ur arrays and move accordingly

Comment: hi Suhail, can uou please give answer of my question that i have asked recently. thank you.

Comment: Hi suhail, I am waiting for your replay.

Comment: Hi suhail. I have asked another question regarding 405 error. Can you please answer it. thank you

Comment: can you please help me.